# Auto-Start ASP.NET Applications

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, iis-7.5

As mentioned here. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Is there another way to do this? By just modifying the application's web.config file?

Comment: Why this method is not enought ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoStart is a feature of the web server and not the application and works only with IIS 7.5 (Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2). Another possibility is to setup a startup script that will send an HTTP request to the application in order to start it.

Comment: just dont want to mess with server settings if not necessary. what about the webserver section of web.config?

Comment: @Rana, sorry this setting is relative to the application pool.

Comment: I found this http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/02/18/preloading-aspnet-applications.aspx but it doesn't say where to place <httpWarmUp> in web.config